# create a weely comparison graph for different users in OBIEE 11g

Tags: oracle, obiee

i have my sql query set .. which pulls out

1. Employee Name
2. Previous week duration
3. Present week duration

I will have 7-8 rows like this

i want to create a graph in OBIEE with employee name on X-axis and on Y

for each employee - previous week+present week pair of bars

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a separate measure using time series functions:

1. Create a new logical column in the BMM layer, call it "Duration - Week ago"
2. Derive from your existing measure column (I guess it is called "Duration")
3. Use the [AGO function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/bi.1111/e10540/dimensions.htm#BABEICGB) as expression, for example:

   ```
   Ago("FactTable"."Duration", "TimeDimension"."Week",1)
   ```
4. Use both measures in your analysis.

You must have a [logical time dimension](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/bi.1111/e10540/dimensions.htm#BABHDIHB) that includes a Week level

Answer (score 0):

when you edit a column formula in Obiee you cannot use the the time dimension hierarchy by selecting it because it is not available but rather you have to write down the path of that dimension manually.
For example "Time"."Time"."Year"

Here first "Time" is the name of folder in which the time hierarchy has been placed and second 'Time" is the hierarchy and third is the name of value e.g Year,Quarter or Month etc.

Hope this helps